# In Power BI, what is the best way to calculate the percentage of filled cells across 5 columns?

Tags: powerbi

I need to calculate the percentage of filled columns in each row across 5 columns of data. In Excel, I can use the following formula and format it as a %:

=SUM(IF(ISTEXT(B2),20%,0),IF(ISTEXT(C2),20%,0),IF(ISTEXT(D2),20%,0),IF(ISTEXT(E2),20%,0),IF(ISTEXT(G2),20%,0))

I know that this probably isn't the best way in Excel either. What is the best way to do this in Power BI?

I have tried a couple of measures using the table and column names, but I can't see to get it right. I feel like there has got to be a much easier way I am overlooking.

So if I had the following two rows, the last column here would be my percentage:

[See example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9oow.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a **calculated column** like this one:

```
Pct Filled = 
    DIVIDE( 
        INT('Table'[Column1] <> "") + INT('Table'[Column2] <> ""), 
        2
    )
```

[image]

Note that in PowerBI a column can have one data type only.